# AMP html support by prestashop or not?

Tags: php

I am trying to apply AMP HTML on PrestaShop CMS, but facing issue with CSS and custom js. Anybody suggested how to convert Prestashop cms website in AMP HTML.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in the Prestashop to convert the pages into AMP. I recommend you to use the **Knowband- Accelerated Mobile Pages** to convert all basic pages such as Product, category, search, CMS pages into AMP.

**Reference Link:** https://www.knowband.com/prestashop-accelerated-mobile-pages

Kindly check the demo of the plugin.